# WPF Displaying a selected range of DataTable rows in Datagrid

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datatable, datagrid, range

So basically, I have a spreadsheet-like application that makes changes on large XML documents. For table display I used DataGrid which is bound to a DataTable. I have two datepickers for selecting the range of rows I want to display. The problem is, I have no idea how, and I wasn't able to find a suitable solution online.

I've tried this as a thing that gets displayed when changes are made to datepickers:

```
return table.AsEnumerable().Skip(StartDateIndex()).Take(DateRange()).CopyToDataTable();
```

...and it works visually, but it's not the same table anymore, so any changes I make on that do not get applied on my collection of data.

Could anyone maybe point me to what would be the right approach to solve this? Or maybe show me an example?

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0):

first you can use the new DataTable in the save logic, or merge it to original DataTable with `table.Merge` method.

also, you can use the CollectionView filter:

```
var collView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(table.Rows) as CollectionView;
collView.Filter = dr => (DateTime)((DataRow)dr)[0] > dtPicker1.Value;
return collView;
```

also, consider using `DataView.RowFilter`:

```
var view = table.DefaultView;
view.RowFilter = string.Format("theFieldDate > #{0}# and theFieldDate < #{1}#",
                                dtPicker1.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), 
                                dtPicker2.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
                              );
return view;
```